# Is SRP related to possible actions of a single class or to their implementation in it?

Tags: c++, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I've read in a lot of places that SRP is a good principle to apply, and I wanted to apply it in my projects.

Actually, it's a game, and my objects have basically two functions `update` and `draw`, so they have two responabilities (defined as a "reason to change"). It could look like this:

```
class Object {
    public:
        void update() {
            // implementation...
        }

        void draw() {
            // implementation...
        }
};
```

Let's say I choose to use the Component design pattern to split `update` and `draw` into an `UpdateComponent` and a `DisplayComponent`, the object which uses these component will still have the pair `update`/`draw`, but not their implementations anymore. So it could look like this now:

```
class Object {
    public:
        void update() {
            m_updateComponent.update(*this);
        }

        void draw() {
            m_displayComponent.draw(*this);
        }

    private:
        UpdateComponent m_updateComponent;

        DisplayComponent m_displayComponent;
};
```

In this implementation, are `update` and `draw` considered as responsabilities of the components **and** of the object, or only the components so the object agrees with the SRP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have considered the "reason to change" and moved it. Now if either the drawing or updating needs to change, you do not need to change the `Object` class. That is all inline with SRP.

However, you have some unnecessary coupling. You can tell because of the two way dependancy between `DisplayComponent` and `Object`. Why does the `Object` need to know about (depend upon) its `DisplayComponent` or even it's `UpdateComponent`?

You have:

```
DisplayComponent <--> Object
```

(the lines represent a dependency, i.e. you can't compile one without the other it is pointing at)

You only need:

```
DisplayComponent ---> Object
```

But then how would you get to the `DisplayComponent` to call `draw`, if you can't do that from the object?

```
ObjectContainer          --\ 
   --> UpdateComponent   ---> Object
   --> DisplayComponent  --/
```

So I have introduced a new `ObjectContainer` class that knows about (depends upon) `UpdateComponent`, `DisplayComponent` and `Object`.

Your outer game loop only has access to `ObjectContainer`s and can only change game state via `m_updateComponent` and draw via `m_displayComponent`. `Object`'s only responsibility now is to persist the state of the object:

```
class Object {
    public:
      //getters/setters maybe

    private:
        int x;
        int y;
        float speed;
        float health;
        //etc
};

class ObjectContainer {
    public:
        void update() {
            m_updateComponent.update(object);
        }

        void draw() {
            m_displayComponent.draw(object);
        }

    private:
        Object object;

        UpdateComponent m_updateComponent;

        DisplayComponent m_displayComponent;
};
```

The above `ObjectContainer` is very similar to your `Object`, but there is no two-way dependency.

Comment: I don't really understand, do you mean that `ObjectContainer` should handle the components, and these components must have an access to the `Object` they work on? And what do you mean by "persist the state of the object"?

Comment: OK, first by "persist the state of the object" I mean it's a game object, so presumably has position, speed, health and other properties. It doesn't need to know how it moves, or how it is drawn, So the `Object` class should have no dependency on `UpdateComponent` or `DisplayComponent`.

Comment: But you could want a class that keeps the drawer, updater and state of the object together, I propose an `ObjectContainer`

Comment: I think I have confused things a little, I will edit.

Comment: Thanks, it's more clear now. But let's say I have maybe two, three, four components like `MovementComponent`, `BattlerComponent`, can I have a function `update` in the `ObjectContainer`?

Comment: Yes you could do. But suppose `UpdateComponent` is an interface, you could plug in `MovementComponent`, or `BattlerComponent` or a `CompositeUpdateComponent` that allows an `Object` to both move and "battle"

Comment: Ok, and how do you make components interact with each over, since I pass to them the `Object` which doesn't have any access to components?

Comment: I don't really understand. You want components to interact?